# PostgreSQL update column with JOIN over 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 3 tables and I want to update `table1` (column `status`) with information (column `status`) from `table2`. the link between `table1` and `table2` is in the table `table_con`

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ce460/4

I thought about a `join` and using the result of the `join` to update `table1`

```
select t1.status as t1status,t2.status as t2status,t1.p_id as t1pid, t2.x_id as t2xid
   from table1 t1
      JOIN table_con tc
      ON t1.p_id = tc.p_id

      JOIN table2 t2 
      ON t2.x_id = tc.x_id;
```

The `join` works so far, but I don't know how to continue,
and the query should work in psql. thanks

Comment: What columns do you want to update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Postgres, you can express joins in the `update` statement:

```
update table1 t1 
   set ?? = ??
   from table_con tc join
        table2 t2 
        on t2.x_id = tc.x_id
   where t1.p_id = tc.p_id;
```

Fill in the `set` column with the column and value you wnt to set.

Comment: What if t1 has to be joined with both tc and t2?

Comment: @AMJ . . . Then you would add another condition in the `WHERE` clause.